# How to increase container memory limit through Pyspark console directly?

Tags: python, apache-spark, memory, pyspark

I am running a Spark job on 16GB nodes and getting error:

```
Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits.  5.6 GB of 5.5 GB physical memory used. 
Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead or disabling yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled because of YARN-4714.
```

How do I increase container memory limits from within console directly? (not before opening Spark shell)?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
conf=SparkConf()
conf.set("spark.executor.memory", "12g")
```

Comment: you have to stop the current spark, first,

and if you are using spark2, use spark.conf.set()